# Android webapp :: landscape display fullscreen

Tags: android, web-applications, fullscreen, android-mediaplayer

I have a small problem. I'm developing a webapp for android and I have been searching tirelessly to find a solution to display a fullscreen mediaplayer when turning the device to landscape (no address bar, just the media).

Much of the stuff out there suggest VideoView which is for native android apps only, however there is not much content on webapp media players and switching to fullscreen. Does anyone know of a solution, or what might work?

Any info sent across is much appreciated and I do apologize if a question has already been answered surrounding this subject.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a web application that's designed specifically for the WebView, you can create interfaces between your JavaScript code and client-side Android code.
See this:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

You can create a class that would detect the screen rotation and if the device is in landscape mode calls a javascript function that would change the mediaplayer to fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Just write down in manifest file in Application tag

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

I think it will be helpful for you.

Comment: and want to full screesn just write NOTitleBarfullscreen

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I believe this is for native applications, not for webapps. If you have any other suggestions please pass along. All info welcome.

Comment: What do u means Native Application ?? i cann't understood

Comment: a native app runs on the actual device OS. A webapp runs on the devices browser, I am developing on the browser.